# Update class property in xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I am working on mobile app using xamarin forms, I have a list of object. I have added the rows in list and raise property using this **OnPropertyChanged** and after save the items i want to update the status of list of object property. How we can update Status Property, Here is my code example , please check the code and update me, Thanks:-

```
class Test
    {
        public int ID{ get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool Status { get; set; }
    }
    class Consume : BaseViewModel
    {
        void main()
        {
            ObservableCollection<Test> coll = new ObservableCollection<Test>();
            coll = await db.GetData();

            foreach (var item in coll)
            {
                item.Status = true;
                //How we can update Status property of class
                OnPropertyChanged("Status");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your `Test` class:

```
    class Test : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        private bool _status;
        public bool Status
        {
            get { return _status; }
            set
            {
                _status = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged implementation

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "")
        {
            Volatile.Read(ref PropertyChanged)?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

And if you have correct binding, after `item.Status = true;` UI will get change of this property.

Comment: , Yes, i have implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged in BaseViewModel. so that i have updated property using this method ** OnPropertyChanged("Status");** but not updated the status.

Comment: `Test` and `BaseViewModel` are different classes. From view model you could update properties that are placed in view model. You should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in `Test` class to update `Status` from `Test`.

Comment: Thanks @Egor Gromadskiy