# How to dynamically change the colour of label? Xamarin

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I got this code below but I can't figure out how to make the selected label be turned into blue background colour and white text instead of what it has in unselected mode. There can only be 1 journey selected at time, and the one that is selected needs to be modified. I figured I could use datatriggers or behaviours. I can figure out how to change the button in the command, but how would I change the other buttons? that gets unselected into gray?

```
<CollectionView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding JourneyItems}" SelectionMode="Single"  ItemsLayout="{x:Static ListItemsLayout.HorizontalList}">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" >
                <StackLayout Margin="10,0,10,0" BackgroundColor="LightGray"  VerticalOptions="Fill"  Orientation="Horizontal" >
                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}"  TextColor="{StaticResource ThemeBkColor}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                </StackLayout>

                <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Path=ViewModel.SwitchJourneyCommand, Source={x:Reference ThisJourneysPage}}"
                        CommandParameter = "{Binding .}" NumberOfTapsRequired="1"/>
                </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

Comment: I haven't used the CollectionView but within your item model, create a property called IsSelected (or something) that drives the color binding and then when another item is selected, loop through all other objects and set IsSelected to false ... or use MessagingCenter to do that ... I'd go with the former method though.  Not sure if that helps but it's a thought.  I assume CollectionView gives you events for when things are selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a `Selected` property to your `JourneyItems` model and then even a BackgroundColor.

```
public class JourneyItem {
    // more stuff

    public bool Selected { get; set; }

    public Color BackgroundColor => Selected ? Color.Blue : Color.Gray;

    public Color TextColor => Selected ? Color.White : Color.Black;
}
```

Then bind the `BackgroundColor` and `TextColor` to change to color X when `Selected` is `true` and color Y otherwise.

```
<Label Text="{Binding Name}"  TextColor="{Binding TextColor}"  BackgroundColor="{Binding BackgroundColor}"/>
```

Finally, in `ViewModel.SwitchJourneyCommand` set your selected model to `true` and all other models to `false`.

```
public void OnJourneyCommand(JourneyItem selectedItem) {
    foreach(JourneyItem item in JourneyItems) {
        item.Selected = item.Id == selectedItem.Id;
    }
}
```

*Edit: To be clear, this will not automatically change colors when `Selected` is changed. Object properties do not automatically bubble up as change events. To do that, you would want to add property changed events to the `Selected` property and have it trigger a change on `BackgroundColor` and `TextColor` when `Selected` gets toggled. Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39350109/3850012

Comment: Why are you using a model to store a visual related state (selected state and color), and why aren't you using a converter instead?

Comment: @slugster To make this example shorter and because converters seem way to heavy in some situations. I like to have models just for my views that can store some visual info. This model would not be the same one that the server and client pass back and forth with.

Comment: @hvaughan3 it’s essentially a ViewModel and it’s an acceptable approach. Good answer. It’s what I suggested in my comment, maybe that’s why I’m biased.  :-)

Comment: @hvaughan3 Then that makes it a *view*model. That makes your approach more acceptable, but using a converter is still the more ideal way to go (and I do agree that converters are frequently misused and abused).

Comment: @slugster A viewmodel is, after all, a model for your view if we are going to split hairs.